# In Talend,The record with the highest salary for the same employee should have true flag else flag should be false

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have an input as

```
ID  Employee    Salary
1   aaa         10000
2   aaa         15000
3   bbb         9000
4   bbb         23000
5   bbb         5000
6   cccc        12000
7   cccc        15000
```

and I need output as below:

```
ID  Employee    Salary  Flag
1   aaa         10000   False
2   aaa         15000   True
3   bbb         9000    False
4   bbb         23000   True
5   bbb         5000    False
6   cccc        12000   False
7   cccc        15000   True
```

Tried with `tJavaRow`. But I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

input------>tJavaRow----->tLogRow

in tJavaRow

```
if(input_row.EMP.equals(context.emp_temp) && input_row.SAL > context.sal_temp) {
output_row.ID = input_row.ID;
output_row.EMP = input_row.EMP;
output_row.SAL = input_row.SAL;
output_row.FLAG = "true";
}
else {

output_row.ID = input_row.ID;
output_row.EMP = input_row.EMP;
output_row.SAL = input_row.SAL;
output_row.FLAG = "false";
}

context.emp_temp = input_row.EMP;
context.sal_temp = input_row.SAL;
```

Comment: will work only if flow sorted by employees, need or add sort component or sorting step